# Python Selenium: reading data from jscontoller

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to find the all the text present with in the div followed by jscontoller = "H6e0Ge"

[image]

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.axis.drawingdesk.v3&hl=en&showAllReviews=true')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontoller='H6eOGe']")
```

However, it returns null value. Could anyone guide me where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Most likely a problem with your xpath. To check if its right or not right click one of the elements and click copy - xpath. Then paste somewhere to see if your path is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Refer an **ESKRY** chrome plugin tool for checking XPATH is correct or not. Try to locate an element and check the result using ESKRY plugin first in chrome browser.

Watch youtube URL for more ESKRY plugin usage details:

https://youtu.be/8V74PsFupis